# Probability of no 6 or no 5 when dice is rolled n times

Tags: probability, dice

Can anyone guide me in the general direction of the answer to the following:

A die is rolled $n$ times

$$A = \text{no $6$s}$$

$$B = \text{no $5$s}$$

$$P(A\cup B) = \;?$$

I am first finding $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ as (where $n$ = 10):

$$P(A)=\left(\frac 56\right)^{10}$$
$$P(B)=\left(\frac 56\right)^{10}$$

$$P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)$$

Is this correct or there is some intersection I have to worry about?

Comment: I think you should first sum up the probability of no 6 or no 5, and then apply it n times. Because now it seems like you roll the dice n times, checking for no 6, then re-roll it n times, checking for no 5. Also I guess, in your case, $n=10$?

Comment: If you roll the die a single time, then your method yields $P(A)=\frac 56 =P(B)$, but if you add these you get a value greater than $1$.  So, yes, the intersection matters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you have to worry about the intersection. Use the formula 
$$P(A \cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A \cap B).$$
In your case 
$$P(A\cap B)=(4/6)^{10}.$$

Comment: Then it means P(A U B) = (5/6)^10 +  (5/6)^10 - (4/6)^10 ??

Comment: Yes, it mean that.